# Print decimal numbers without DECIMAL word and without float conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal

I performed a simple normalizing process:

```
a = range(5)
norm = [Decimal(i)/sum(a) for i in a]
print norm
```

Output:

```
[Decimal('0'), Decimal('0.1'), Decimal('0.2'), Decimal('0.3'), Decimal('0.4')]
```

But I just want it to print:

```
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

How do I rectify this? Please help.

PS: This is just a sample I tried. My actual data has huge floating point numbers. I want to do this to avoid the floating point errors. I want the results to be in decimals and not in float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use print(str(Decimal)) instead of print(Decimal) :

```
print [str(i) for i in norm]
['0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4']
```

Answer (score 1):

To **print** Decimals without the 'Decimal' appearing, you could subclass Decimal and override `__repr__`:

```
>>> class MyDecimal(Decimal):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return str(float(self))
...
>>> x = Decimal(4.1)
>>> x
Decimal('4.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375')
>>> y = MyDecimal(5.3)
>>> y
5.3
```

However, when you do any operation with them, the `repr` goes back to it's original form:

```
>>> y = MyDecimal(5.3)
>>> z = MyDecimal(4.2)
>>> y + z
Decimal('9.500000000000000000000000000')
```

To always get `MyDecimal` in such cases, you would need to override all of `Decimal`'s operations to return a `MyDecimal` obeject instead of `Decimal`.

Note that what we're seeing here is the representation of the decimal. And you will need to leave that as is when doing other operations. Or always convert to float when using it elsewhere. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal):

> Decimal objects cannot generally be combined with floats in arithmetic operations: an attempt to add a Decimal to a float, for example, will raise a TypeError. There’s one exception to this rule: it’s possible to use Python’s comparison operators to compare a float instance x with a Decimal instance y. Without this exception, comparisons between Decimal and float instances would follow the general rules for comparing objects of different types described in the Expressions section of the reference manual, leading to confusing results.